# False branch of ternary expression consumes trailing string while concatenating

Tags: php, html, foreach, concatenation, conditional-operator

I can't figure it out, why I get such a thing:

[image]

It is not infinite.

The `workingList` array has only 3 records:

```
if ($workerList) {
    foreach ($workerList as $worker) {
        $option .= '<option value="' . $worker["name"] . '" '  
            . ($worker["name"] === $b["worker"])
              ? "selected='selected'"
              : "" . '>' . $worker['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    var_dump($option);
}
```

Did I mess up with quotes?

P.S. `$b["worker"]` can be null or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following.

```
if ($workerList) {
    foreach ($workerList as $worker)
    {
        $selected_value = ($worker["name"] === $b["worker"]) ? "selected" : "";
        $worker_name = $worker["name"];
        $option .= '<option value="' . $worker_name . '" ' . $selected_value . '>' . $worker_name . '</option>';
    }
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: That did work. But still don't get it, why can't it be in one line without additional variables...

Comment: It can be write in a line too but for writting in an efficient way it the good way to write it

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you've experienced is an issue in the realm of "encapsulationg".

Your:

```
$option .= '<option value="' . $worker["name"] . '" ' . ($worker["name"] === $b["worker"]) ? "selected='selected'" : "" . '>' . $worker['name'] . '</option>';
```

Is the same as saying:

```
$option .= '<option value="' . $worker["name"] . '" ';
if ($worker["name"] === $b["worker"]) {
    $option .= "selected='selected'";
} else {
    $option .= "" . '>' . $worker['name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Because you didn't use parentheses to encapsulate the entire ternary expression, the "else" branch gobbled up all of the trailing text.

Put more simply, your code is this:

```
(condition) ? 'true branch' : 'false branch' . ' trailing text'
```

But your coding intent is:

```
(condition ? 'true branch' : 'false branch') . ' trailing text'
```

---

Your code could be corrected as:

```
$option .= '<option value="' . $worker["name"] . '" ' . ($worker["name"] === $b["worker"] ? "selected='selected'" : "") . '>' . $worker['name'] . '</option>';
```

But I have a strong distaste for messy concatenation/interpolation when adding multiple variables and/or conditions to a string.

Also, there is never any need to declare the `value` attribute of an option tag if it is identical to the option's visible text.  All form submissions and javascript will work seamlessly.

I recommend the following:

```
$option .= sprintf(
    '<option%s>%s</option>',
    $worker['name'] === $b['worker'] ? ' selected' : '',
    htmlspecialchars($worker['name'])
);
```